# iphone order of json array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

I have an iPhone application which gets a json string from a server and parses it. It contains some data e.g. school timetable information. The data is stored in an nsdictionary and then passed into a nsmuttablearray. e.g.

Could someone please point me in the right direction/tell me how i can access the different 'roots' of the array? I want to store the elements that have the field 'Day' as "Monday" (or maybe u can tell me how i can sort/do a search though them). Been spending quite some time trying to find some information on this (how to access/alter nested values) but no luck =/. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet for accessing all of the Dictionary objects with Day = Monday would be to use a Predicate with a Key Path to what you're after...

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Day == 'Monday'"];
NSArray* mondayCourses = [rows filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

You can make the predicate dynamic too.

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Day == %@", dayOfTheWeek];
```

where dayOfTheWeek might be an NSString that holds the current day of the week in a loop etc.

If you want to sort the array, you can do so using Sort Descriptors.

```
NSSortDescriptor* idSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id" 
                                                                   ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor* levelSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Level" 
                                                                      ascending:YES];
NSArray* sortedMondayRows = [mondayRows sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:idSortDescriptor, levelSortDescriptor, nil]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In regards to the predicate, when i attempt to pass value, e.g. rows = mondayCourses my program crashes and there isnt anything in console. rows is of nsarray format, u have any ideas?

Comment: If I'm looking at your example JSON structure correctly, your NSDictionary "rows" will hold only 1 key/value pair with the key "Array". 

So you will want to create an array like so: 

NSArray* courses = [rows objectForKey:@"Array"]; 

Then you can use my predicate code almost verbatim (just change [rows filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; to [courses filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];)

Comment: You're welcome. I've been elbow deep in this sort of thing for months & it's almost become second nature!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your JSON is correct in the URL : http://jsonlint.com/. 
If its correct than read on how to Parse JSON file by googling.
Are you using any specific framework for parsing JSON files ?

Comment: the parsing of the json is fine i just dont understand how to manipulate the data once i have it into a muttablearray (what i posted above is inside the array)

Answer (score 0):

Start out by looking at the Apple documentation for [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) and [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In this case, it looks like the array (an NSArray) contains a number of NSDictionaries.

> The data is stored in an nsdictionary and then passed into a nsmuttablearray.

First, I must note that variables in Objective-C are just pointers. When you have a line like this:

```
NSMutableArray *rows;
```

You are only saying, “I expect this variable to point to an NSMutableArray.” It is pretty much equivalent to,

```
id rows;
```

…and you will not be stopped, at runtime, from putting a regular array in a variable which was declared for mutable arrays (or putting a string in a variable which was declared for a dictionary!). It will work! But your program will crash when you try to do mutable things to a non-mutable array, or dictionary things to a string.

Declaring it as a pointer to an NSMutableArray, instead of id, has a few advantages:

- It lets XCode help you out by autocompleting method names
- It lets the compiler warn you when you try to call methods that NSMutableArray doesn’t have

So, even if your variable is declared as `NSMutableArray *rows`, on this line:

```
rows = [[dict objectForKey:@"courses"] retain];
```

…if the “courses” object was not mutable, what you have in `rows` is not either. Instead, you can do this:

```
rows = [[dict objectForKey:@"courses"] mutableCopy];
```

…to get your own NSMutableArray copy of the array (which you have to release, just as if you retained the original).

---

You explore the array and dictionaries with standard Cocoa code. Here would be one way to get all of the “Monday” courses:

```
NSMutableArray *mondayCourses = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary* course in rows){
    if([[course objectForKey:@"Day"] isEqual:@"Monday"]){
        [mondayCourses addObject:course];
    }
}
```

(Warning, I have not run this code.)