# How to rearrange NSDictionary according to the values?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I need to list all dictionary values. Like highest mark to lowest. How can I handle this?

I need to list all marks and corresponding names and details in a table view.

```
2015-04-06 14:48:53.381 camelProject[3310:597950] valueforkey title = (
    {
    CamelID = 237;
    Color = bg;
    Comments = "Fhjfnfnfjfihgjfmsndidm,almcmcuirowmvn vmmc Jdmdmcm";
    CompID = 235;
    DateOfBirth = "/Date(1424725200000)/";
    Description = "rtrtttrtrehndskvn;lkdf;lm;mgemln;lm';' jknt;l";
    FromUserID = 564987631;
    FromUsername = 564987631;
    ID = 4;
    IndvMarks = "5;5;3;4;2;2;2;2;5;9";
    Marks = 39;
    Name = name3sv;
    OutOF = 100;
    ProfilePhoto = "2D0B36F3-71B3-4B5F-A375-7AD4D0AFF1AF.jpg\n";
    TOname = hasnam;
    ToUserName = 564987631;
    Types = dsfv;
    UserID = 564987631;
    fromname = hasnam;
},
    {
    CamelID = 237;
    Color = bg;
    Comments = "";
    CompID = 235;
    DateOfBirth = "/Date(1424725200000)/";
    Description = "rtrtttrtrehndskvn;lkdf;lm;mgemln;lm';' jknt;l";
    FromUserID = 564987631;
    FromUsername = 564987631;
    ID = 5;
    IndvMarks = "5;4;5;7;6;0;6;5;4;6";
    Marks = 48;
    Name = name3sv;
    OutOF = 100;
    ProfilePhoto = "2D0B36F3-71B3-4B5F-A375-7AD4D0AFF1AF.jpg\n";
    TOname = hasnam;
    ToUserName = 564987631;
    Types = dsfv;
    UserID = 564987631;
    fromname = hasnam;
},
    {
    CamelID = 237;
    Color = bg;
    Comments = Gucjhkhvnkvnvnvknkjbkvjhvvkb;
    CompID = 235;
    DateOfBirth = "/Date(1424725200000)/";
    Description = "rtrtttrtrehndskvn;lkdf;lm;mgemln;lm';' jknt;l";
    FromUserID = 564987631;
    FromUsername = 564987631;
    ID = 6;
    IndvMarks = "3;4;4;3;5;4;4;3;3;5";
    Marks = 38;
    Name = name3sv;
    OutOF = 100;
    ProfilePhoto = "2D0B36F3-71B3-4B5F-A375-7AD4D0AFF1AF.jpg\n";
    TOname = hasnam;
    ToUserName = 564987631;
    Types = dsfv;
    UserID = 564987631;
    fromname = hasnam;
},
    {
    CamelID = 236;
    Color = wejr;
    Comments = "Jfj ki idhvjfn isms isn't if jfj Jen hik";
    CompID = 235;
    DateOfBirth = "/Date(1427058000000)/";
    Description = jwenrfernkgr;
    FromUserID = 564987631;
    FromUsername = 564987631;
    ID = 21;
    IndvMarks = "8;6;10;10;10;7;5;8;9;5";
    Marks = 78;
    Name = name;
    OutOF = 100;
    ProfilePhoto = "E7735AF4-8EAB-41E7-A3F2-3280DBED0389.jpg\n";
    TOname = lukman;
    ToUserName = 564987634;
    Types = wenjewfn;
    UserID = 564987634;
    fromname = hasnam;
}
)
```

Comment: try like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851398/iphone-order-of-json-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the values into a array and sort them using a sort descriptor.

```
NSArray *array = [dictioanry objectForKey:@"title"];

NSSortDescriptor* marksDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Marks"
                                                                      ascending:YES];
NSArray* sortedObjects = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:marksDescriptor, nil]];

//YOu can put this object back into NSDictionary if you want it for later
```

I think your dictionary should be looking like this.

[image]

So the code above should work to sort the values. Here is the sample code that I did the testing with.

**Note: Save your JSON string in your test.json and add it to your project. [or download the file from here](http://pastebin.com/JBj8BiYg) and add it to your project**

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];


    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:data
                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                              error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@",jsonDictionary);

    NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];

    NSSortDescriptor* marksDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Marks"
                                                                      ascending:YES];
    NSArray* sortedObjects = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:marksDescriptor, nil]];


    NSLog(@"%@",sortedObjects);
```

Comment: thank your fast response, ok but how,am using xml parser to parse the datas, service returns json values, then take tis into nsdictionary , my dictionary values are i posted above ,just check and help me

Comment: @islahul I have updated the post with a sample JSON

Comment: @ Priyatham51 , tried many times but exception   [__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ce4d680
2015-04-07 10:47:54.653 camelProject[51999:2028442] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ce4d680'

Comment: It looks like you are having them in a array and not in a NSDictionay.

Comment: Can you show me the line of code where you have objectForKey

Comment: _commonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                          error:&jsonError];
    
    NSArray *array = [_commonDict objectForKey:@"title"];
    
    NSSortDescriptor* marksDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Marks"
                                                                      ascending:YES];
    NSArray* sortedObjects = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:marksDescriptor, nil]];

Comment: _commonDict  datas i posted on my code @priyatham51

Comment: put a break point after this line commonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError]; and print the _commonDict. and also verify that variable in variables view is matching to the image that I posted.

Comment: i used same codes but exception is came like that i showed you na like that ,please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74617/discussion-between-priyatham51-and-islahul).

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
NSArray *originalArray = @[
                               @{@"page_no": @"27"},
                               @{@"page_no": @"1"},
                               @{@"page_no": @"12"},
                               @{@"page_no": @"23"},
                               @{@"page_no": @"3"},
                               @{@"page_no": @"2"},
                               @{@"page_no": @"17"},
                               ];

    NSSortDescriptor *alphaNumSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"page_no"
                                                                 ascending:YES
                                                                comparator:^(NSString *string1, NSString *string2)
    {
        return [string1 compare:string2 options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];


    NSArray *sortedArray = [originalArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[alphaNumSD]];
    NSLog(@"%@", sortedArray);
```

Output :

```
(
        {
        "page_no" = 1;
    },
        {
        "page_no" = 2;
    },
        {
        "page_no" = 3;
    },
        {
        "page_no" = 12;
    },
        {
        "page_no" = 17;
    },
        {
        "page_no" = 23;
    },
        {
        "page_no" = 27;
    }
)
```

It definitely works as expected.